# Who are these goddesses?

Tags: avatars, devi

In the Devi Bhagvata Purana, in the rules for performing the Kumari Puja, it said that girls embody certain goddesses according to their age:

> 41-43. The virgin aged two years is named the **Kumârî** ; aged three years is named the **Trimurtî** four years, is called the **Kalyânî** ; five years, **Rohinî**; six years, Kâlikâ; seventh year, Chandikâ; eighth year, **S’âmbhavî** ; ninth year, Dûrgâ; and a virgin, aged ten years, is called **Subhadrâ** . Virgins aged more than ten years are not allowed in all ceremonies.

Who are these goddesses? The only goddesses I know of (a little bit) are Rohini and Subhadra. Rohini is the wife of Chandra, the moon god, and Subhadra is the sister of Krishna(I am not really sure if Subhadra is the avatar of the goddess who Kansa tried to kill, as I think she became Vidhya Vasini) and both goddesses have not, to my knowledge, displayed the power as goddesses.As for their roles, the Devi Bhagvata Purana says this:

> **45. The worship of Kumârî leads to the extinction of miseries and poverty, to the extirpation of one’s enemies and the increment of riches, longevity and power.**
>
> **46. The Trimurtî Pujâ yields longevity, and the acquisition of the three things, Dharma, wealth, and desires, the coming in of riches, sons and grandsons.**
>
> 47. **Those who want learning, victory, kingdom and happiness, they should worship the Kalyânî, the fructitier of all desires.**
>
> **48-49. Men should worship Rohinî duly for the cure of diseases.** For the destruction of enemies, the worship of the Kâlikâ with devotion is the best. For prosperity and riches, Chandikâ is to be worshipped with devotion. O king! **For the enchanting and overpowering of one’s enemies, for the removal of miseries and poverty, and for victory in battles, S’âmbhavî worship is the best.**
>
> 50-51. For the destruction of awfully terrible enemies and for happiness in the next world, the worship of Dûrgâ is the safest and best. **People worship Subhadrâ when they want their desires to be fulfilled**

It is also said that:

> **53. The Goddess who can create without any difficulty all the sacred tattvas of the Kumâr Kârtikeya and who effects, as if in sport, the creation of all the Devas Brahmâ and others; I am worshiping the same Kumârî Devî.**
>
> **54. She who is appearing under the three forms as differentiated by the three gunas Sâttva, Râjas, and Tâmas, and who is appearing in multiple forms, owing to the differentiations of the three gunas again into various minor differences, I am worshipping Her the Trimûrtî Devî.**
>
> **55. She who being worshipped always fares us with auspicious things, I am worshipping Her, with devotion, the Kumârî Kalyânî, the awarder of all desires.**
>
> **56. I am worshipping the Rohinî Devî with a heart, full of devotion who is germinating all the karmas in seed forms, that have accumulated owing to past deeds.**
>
> 57. She who, at the end of a Kalpa gathers unto Her in the form of Kâlî all this Universe, moving and unmoving, I worship that Kâlikâ Devî with devotion.
> 58. She, who is furious and wrathful and hence is called Chandikâ and who killed the two Demons Chanda and Munda I bow down to Her humbly with devotion, to that Chandikâ Devî, who destroys the terrible sins.
>
> **59. I worship that S’âmbhavî Devî, the giver of all pleasures and happiness, whose form is the Veda Brahmâ, and whose origin is without any cause, and whe is so recited in the Vedas.**
>
> 60. She who saves from danger her devotees and who always delivers from various difficulties and troubles, whom all the Devas are incapable to know, I worship with devotion that Dûrgâ Devî the destroyer of all calamities.
>
> **61. I, with my mind devoted, offer my salutations to that Subhadrâ Devî, Who procures all auspiciousness to Her devotees and removes all inauspicious incidents.**

Who are these goddesses? Are they mentioned in any other texts?

Comment: I had also read the bhagwat and this part. I think these goddesses are no more than mother Lalita herself. There is no distinction

Comment: They are IMO different names for different age groups of a girl.

Comment: @Surya If they are different names for different age groups, how are they, for example, "theorgin wothout any cause"? In any case, are there any imdividual stories about them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they are mentioned in many Tantra texts like the **KulArnava Tantram, PurascharjArnava** etc.

For example the following verse mentions when to worship the Nava Kumaris.

> Iswara Uvacha:
>
> **Kurjannava KumArinAm PujAmAsvinmAsake |**
>
> PrAtarnimantrayedbhaktyA SAdhakah SuddhamAnasaha ||
>
> ### Meaning
>
> Lord Shiva said:
>
> **In the Asvin month puja of Navakumaris are to be done**. The devotee
>   should invite them in the morning with a pure mind.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 10-20**

In another Shakta text called the PurascharjArnava maidens aged one year to sixteen years are defined to be the Kumaris. Their names are as follows:

> SandhyA ( 1-year old), Saraswati, TridhAmurthi, KAlikA, SubhagA, UmA,
>   MAlini, KubjikA, KAlangkarshA, AparAjitA, RudrAni, Bhairavi,
>   MahAlakshmi, KulanAyikA, KshetragyA and ChadikA (16-years old).

However, regarding the names, there is a difference of opinion. In KulArnava Tantram, for example, different names are mentioned:

> BAla SuddhA Cha LalitA MAlini Cha VasundharA |
>
> Saraswati RamA Gouri DurgA Cha Nava KeerthitAha ||
>
> ### Meaning
>
> BAla, SuddhA, LalitA, MAlini, Vasundhara, Sarswati, RamA, Gauri and
>   Durga are the 9 [Kumaris].
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 10-27.**

Now whether they are some specific Goddesses (as it might seem from their names) , then they are not. These Pujas are done to please the Supreme Goddess like  Lalita etc. These girls are treated as Devi herself.

And, while doing the Puja the sadhaka should be able to visualize his Ishta Devata ( like Lalita, Durga, Mahakali etc) in the kumaris and do the Puja as if they are worshiping their Ishtas only. This is mentioned in the following verse:

> BAlAmalankritAm Pasyan **Chintayeth SwestadevatAm** |
>
> ### Meaning
>
> The sadhaka upon seeing the Kumaris decked in ornaments **should think
>   about their own Ishta Devatas.**
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 10-25.**

And, instead of worshiping Kumaris, worship of Yuvatis in Devi SWarupa are also prescribed. And their names as given below are mentioned in the same chapter:

> HrillekhA, GananA, RaktA, MahattundA, KarAlikA, IcchA, GyanA, KriyA
>   and DurgA are the Navayuvatis.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 10-35.**

**NOTE**- KulArnava Tantram 10-35 means verse 35 in chapter 10 of that text.

Comment: BTW where did u get the tantra online? Could you send me the links to the tantras too plz?

Comment: @KVickneshvara I have hard copies. I do not have much PDF. In any case if u tell which particular tantra text u want i can try.

Comment: Oh... Erm any tantra I guess...

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The answer includes all possible Devis or other entities linked with the 9 names mentioned in Shrimad Devi Bhagwatam for Kumari Puja.

**Kumārī (कुमारी)** refers to a “virgin” and is used to describe Goddess Durgā.
Kumari or Kaumari refers to one of the seven mother-like goddesses (Matrika)—

> The Matrikas emerge as shaktis from out of the bodies of the gods: Kaumari from Skanda. The order of the Saptamatrka usually begins with Brahmi symbolizing creation. Then, Vaishnavi and Maheshvari. Then, Kaumari, Guru-guha, the intimate guide in the cave of one’s heart, inspires aspirations to develop and evolve.

Not nessecarily, Kumari is the matrika as Kumārī (कुमारी) is the name of the Yakṣiṇī associated with Oḍḍiyāna, one the eight Sacred Seats (pīṭha), according to the Yogakhaṇḍa (chapter 14) of the Manthānabhairavatantra.
Thus, Kumari can be any of the two entities. Same applies with all devi mentioned below.

**Trimūrti (त्रिमूर्ति)** refers to one of the six Goddesses (parā-ṣaṭka) associated with Kāmākhya. The six Goddesses (parāṣaṭka) are- Kāmārtā, Retasā,** Trimūrti**, Ūdhikā, Nityā, Mahocchūṣmā.

**Kalyani** is the name of devi in the shaktipeeth of Malayachala.

**Rohiṇī (रोहिणी)** refers to one of the eight Kaula consorts (dūtī-aṣṭaka) associated with Tisrapīṭha (located in the ‘end of sound’—nādānta), according to the Manthānabhairavatantra.
The eight Kaula consorts (dūtyaṣṭaka) are- Revatī, Bhagavatī, Rāmā, **Rohiṇī**, Kṛttikā, Khecarī, Khaṇḍinī, Kṣānti.
Rohini is also daughter of Daksha. She was married to Chandra, the moon, alongwith twenty-six of her sisters. The twenty-seven sisters are the twenty-seven constellations in Indian Astrology.
Rohiṇī is also the consort of Mahādeva (aspect of Śiva in one of the eight names of Rudra) according to the Pādma-purāṇa.

**Kālikā (कालिका)** refers to the daughter of Himavat.
Kālikā (कालिका) is also the name of the Peethadishwari (avvā) associated with the sacred seat of Jālandhara (jālapītha), according to the Manthānabhairavatantra.

**Caṇḍikā (चण्डिका)** is the name of a Mātṛkā-Śakti created by Mahārudra in order to control the plague of demons created by Andhakāsura.
Caṇḍikā (चण्डिका) also refers to one of the six Goddesses (parā-ṣaṭka) associated with Jālandhara (which is in the southern quarter), according to the Manthānabhairavatantra.

**Śāmbhavī** was the name of Parvati in the 3rd kalpa. And this are mentioned as below-
According to the Tantrasadbhāva chapter 10:

> O eternal one, she appeared in order to grace the worlds. In the third aeon (kalpa) (she was) **Śāmbhavī**.

Skanda Maha Puranam, 1st Skandha- Prabhāsa kṣetra māhātmya, Chapter7 - The Appearance (Origin) of [Somanath](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626794.html),

**Bhagawan Shiva said,**

> 28. In the third (Kalpa) you were (known by the) name **Śāmbhavī** and in the fourth Viśvarūpiṇī. In the fifth you were named Nandinī and in the sixth Gaṇāṃbikā.

**Durga (दुर्गा)** is the name of the Goddes in her fifth of seven births, according to the second recension of the Yogakhaṇḍa of the Manthānabhairavatantra.
Accordingly, as the Lord said to Bhadrakālī:

> “ (Coming from) Himavat’s house you were married (to me) for seven rebirths. In the first (birth your) name (was) Subhagā and Kāladūtī in the second birth. You (were) Revatī in the third and Mokṣalakṣmī in the fourth. You (were) **Durga** in the fifth birth and Jayeśvarī in the sixth. In the previous birth—the seventh—you (were) Umā, my favourite.

Here durga could even mean devi Parvati who Slayed Durgamasur.

**Subhadrā (सुभद्रा)**:—Sanskrit name of one of the thirty-two female deities of the Somamaṇḍala (second maṇḍala of the Khecarīcakra) according to the kubjikāmata-tantra. These goddesses are situated on a ring of sixteen petals and represent the thirty-two syllables of the Aghoramantra. Each deity (including Subhadrā) is small, plump and large-bellied. They can assume any form at will, have sixteen arms each, and are all mounted on a different animal.
Also, she can be the sister of Shree Krishn, as Subhadrā in Jaggannath Puri is worshipped as Bhuvaneshwari Mahavidya.

[image]

All glories to Bhagwati alone...

**श्री कालिकार्पणमस्तु ।**

Comment: Who are these nine goddesses in the two pictures?

Comment: This was used for the Representation purpose of 9 girls to be viewed as a form of Devi. In reality this image is of Agni Durga. Why do the painter has slightly change the mudras of Devi  as mentioned in Dhyan. Refer to this answer you had asked    https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/52236/27796