# These Dhyana Slokas belong to which deity?

Tags: durga-saptasati

The below Dhyana Slokas found in chapter 12 and 13 of Durga Saptashati .

Dhyana Sloka of chapter 12 in Durga Saptashati

> vidhyuddhāma samaprabhāṃ mṛgapati skandha sthitāṃ bhīṣaṇāṃ।
> kanyābhiḥ karavāla khēṭa vilasaddastābhi rāsēvitāṃ
> hastaiśchakra gadhāsi khēṭa viśikhāṃ guṇaṃ tarjanīṃ
> vibhrāṇa manalātmikāṃ śiśidharāṃ durgāṃ trinētrāṃ bhajē

Dhyana Sloka of chapter 13 in Durga Saptashati

> om bālārka maṇḍalābhāsāṃ chaturbāhuṃ trilōchanām pāśānkuśa varābhītīrdhārayantīṃ śivāṃ bhajē

So my question is These Dhyana Slokas belong to which deity and what is the meaning of these dhyana slokas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Agni Durga

2. Tripurā Parvati**

The translation of dhyaan mentioned in 12th chapter is as follows,

> I meditate upon the three eyed Durgadevi, her complexion is like that of lightening(luminous). She is riding on the shoulders of a lion & looks terrifying. Carrying swords & shield many young girls are standing in her service. She (Agni durga) carries disc, conch, sword, shield, arrow, bow, noose & displays tarjani mudra ( warning mudra, showing index finger to scare evil ). Her form is like that of fire and she has a moon on her diadem.

[image]

[image]

Thus she is **Agni Durga**, one of the numerous Durga devis. It is said that, Hinglaj devi of Hingul Shaktipeeth is too Agni Durga.

The translation of the dhyaan in 13th chapter is as follows,

> I meditate upon that Shivā devi, who has the complexion of the rising sun, has four hands and three eyes, who carries Pasha(noose), Ankush (Goad), Var (fulfilment) & Abhaya (fear not) mudras.

[image]

She is **Tripurā Parvati**, one of the six forms of Parvati devi. Usually, mentioned in angapuja.

(Ps- The image used here doesn't show 3 eyes.
Also,do not confuse Tripurā Parvati with Bhuvaneshwari devi, as the moon is missing on the diadem of former & also tge complexion of latter is like rising sun.)

**कालिकार्पणमस्तु ।**

Comment: I read Uma Samhita of Shiva Purana now. Uma Devi appeared to destroy the proud of Devas. She holds Ankush (goad), Pasha (noose), Vara (boon) and Abhaya Mudra (mystic gesture of protection). So, Uma Devi and Tripura Parvati is same.

Comment: Yes indeed. As I already mentioned Tripurā Parvati is one of the six forms of Uma.

Comment: Can you answer to my new question? I give the link:- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/52802/who-is-goddess-kameshwari

Comment: Sure, sir will jot down the answer asap,,once Durga Puja is done. Kindly bear till then.